# ArcPy Python script - Runtime Error: ERROR 010240: could not save raster dataset to C:\L_B2dpy with output format GRID

Tags: python, image-processing, arcpy

I m working on a script with python and arcpy to process Landsat satellite images. Near the end of the script of get an error at the same location each time. The error occurs after one successful run of the code (i.e. the error occurs on the second occurrence of the same task)

---

```
print "Starting Rt_B2dpy (2 of 4)"
if arcpy.Exists(Rt_B2dpy):
    arcpy.Delete_management(Rt_B2dpy)
Rt_B2dpy = Rt2 - 1
Rt_B2dpy.save("Rt_B2dpy")
print "Rt_B2dpy has been created"
```

---

I have env.overwriteOutput set to True so that is not the problem.

I gave this code to a friend to run and they got it to process all 4 occurrences of this block of code but their output is blank. I also used there modified script (change some path entries)and got this error at the same location as the first one:

exceptions.EOFError:[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

This error crashed python and the editor.

The script produces a grid for the first run, but the second one creates a grid that is unreadable in ArcGIS.

I m working from a windows virtual machine (parallels) on a mac with 8 GB of RAM. The virtual machine is using 4 GB of RAM.

I have not clue what is going on or how to debug it! Any help would be much appreciated.

WORKAROUND = I found a work around by saving the output as a TIF image rather than a Raster file.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure some obvious things aren't the problem:

1) have you set arcpy.env.workspace, arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace? Presuming this is outside a gdb, so you don't need arcpy.env.scratchFolder set (only applies in ArcGIS 10.1+, I think).

2) is there actually enough disk space? I've gotten that not-so-helpful message about "forcible" close when I've run out of space.

3) bit of voodoo, but maybe fully specify the pathname to which output will be save, instead of the local name only that you show in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked my script I saw that I didn't put \ at the end of the output folder. So maybe you've missed the same thing